# Solved! Cross product in parallelogram

Tags: vectors, cross-product

The area of the parallelogram $ABCD$ is equal to: $$\text{Area} = \left|\vec{AB}\times\vec{AD}\right|\text.$$
Is it the same for $$\text{Area} = \left|\vec{AC}\times\vec{AD}\right|\text?$$
Because both will derive into the height and the base. If this is true, can we somehow prove: $$\left|\vec{AB}\times\vec{AD}\right| = \left|\left(\vec{AB}+\vec{AD}\right)\times\vec{AD}\right|$$

Thanks!

[Parallelogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsjmQ.jpg)

Comment: Note that $\vec{AD}\times \vec{AD}=\vec0$

Comment: Oh yeah. Stupid me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, using [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Algebraic_properties) of the cross product, $$ \left|\left(\vec{AB}+\vec{AD}\right)\times\vec{AD}\right|=
\left|\vec{AB}\times\vec{AD}+\vec{AD}\times\vec{AD}\right |=$$

$$\left| \vec{AB}\times\vec{AD}+\vec{0} \right |=\left|\vec{AB}\times\vec{AD}\right| . $$